# Value of a degree from an unknown univeristy

Tags: phd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [University rank/stature - How much does it affect one’s career post-Ph.D?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d)

I graduated with a Bacholars from a top university and did quite well, however, I was recommended to a professor in an unknown (read as not highly ranked) university for a PhD program. I had certainly not heard of the university before, and I don't believe that it has much of a reputation. It is not a new university by any means (established 1800s).

Is a degree from such an University likely to add value to me? Also, how do I know whether this is a step in the right direction (before I take it)?

Edit: I am considering it because the research that is performed by the professor there interests me.

Comment: The age of a university means nothing for its rank in various disciplines. Most of the top public institutions in the US were founded in the 1800s.

Comment: This does seems to be an exact duplicate to the question mentioned by @JukkaSuomela. The answers there cover this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Your publication record at the end is what will count most.

Comment: Hi Dave, could you please elaborate on your answer, this is my first time hearing about a "publication record"