# Is Ph.D relevant in academics because of the university under which it is done or the paper publications?

Tags: phd

Is Ph.D relevant in academics because of the university under which it is done or the paper publications? I am planning to join for Ph.D under a relatively new university but I hear often that it's the papers that count and the quality papers in it. The university as long as it's registered with the government / legal doesn't matter. Is that true?

Comment: See this: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/154/10042