# Is a PhD from a weak university worthless?

Tags: phd, university

I did my PhD in pure mathematics at a university which does not have a good reputation in
mathematics. At that time, I did not know that most British universities are quite weak
in maths. Apart from that, my PhD advisor is not a great mathematician.

After graduation, all of my applications for a postdoc position failed. My advisor was not helpful
in the application process. Could the reason for this be the fact that my PhD has been awarded by a weak institution? Do they consider it as worthless? If so, how can I overcome this problem?
A second PhD is not an option for me.

At this point I should mention, that my all of my PhD colleagues (working in the same field as me)
who were at strong and famous universities were successful in finding a postdoc position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [University rank/stature - How much does it affect one's career post-Ph.D?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d)

Comment: Attracting grants, publications and networking are quite more important than where you did your PhD. If someone rejects you outright not on the interest of your topic and the merit of your work but on the name of the institution, you don't want to work with, or in the same place, as that someone.