# What criteria are used to rank graduate programs?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, united-states

I'm only asking this out of curiosity since I've seen posts/discussions about getting into "top" graduate programs etc. This mentally (wanting to get into a "top" ranked program) makes sense (depending on one's priorities) for undergraduate study, since the selectivity is what gives the degree its "prestige."  This may also hold true for law or medical school programs where rankings may reflect the level of training one receives and/or directly affect internship/residency opportunities etc. However, I'm not sure how this would apply to a research degree.

For example, in masters or PhD research programs, you're applying to conduct research under the auspices of a specific advisor. Thus, it seems that alignment of research interests and personal compatibility should be prioritized over "rank" of the program. Obviously one still has to meet certain admissions criteria regardless of the program they're applying to, but it doesn't make sense (to me anyway) to rank/judge research oriented graduate programs the way one would an undergraduate or "professional" program (i.e medical or law school etc).

Also, will the quality of one's graduate education or future academic career opportunities be affected by the rank of the program? Personally, my main priorities are location combined with compatibility of an advisor. However, I was curious as to what criteria are used to rank graduate programs and why would one prioritize rank of program over other factors.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90/68109

Comment: Are you asking about "rank" in the sense of the formal rankings that are published by various organizations (and which usually disclose their methodology), or in the more informal sense of "which ones people generally agree are better"?

Comment: I was referring to formal ranking ( I'm in a humanities field. but I was speaking more generally.)  When someone says, for example, "I want to get into a top 20 program," I'm assuming that those are formally ranked programs (vs. the person's subjective opinion of the school/program).

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "emotional-responses"?

Comment: I thought there was an emotional aspect involved since people may feel strongly about their opinions either way (i.e. valuing the student/advisor relationship over rank of the school or vice versa).

Comment: @Gemini that's not what this tag is about.

Answer (score 1):

> What criteria are used to rank graduate programs?

Before enrolling in a PhD program, you should identify your personal goals and needs, and evaluate graduate programs yourself according to your own criteria.  When doing so, consider life both during and after your graduate studies.  Mathematical formulas for ranging graduate programs do exist, but they are inaccurate and measure something different from your personal needs.  An applicant to a graduate program should be sophisticated enough to perform their own evaluation based on a range of data sources.

In short:  Don't rank graduate programs in same way universities are ranked.

Further, your supervisor is usually more important than your program.

> Also, will the quality of one's graduate education or future academic career opportunities be affected by the rank of the program?

This is a duplicate.  [University rank/stature - How much does it affect one's career post-Ph.D?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90/68109)

Comment: "Don't rank graduate programs in same way universities are ranked.  Further, your supervisor is usually more important than your program." I agree, and that's why I posted this. I see others mentioning  wanting to get into "top" programs, and I wanted to know why they would prioritize rank over advisor at the graduate level.

Comment: Rank is prioritized out of ignorance.  However, if your future employer is ignorant (and most employers are not experts in academia) then you should prioritize the way your future employer prioritizes.