# Is there anything that resembles an algorithm for success in academia?

Tags: career-path

There are algorithms/prescriptions for treating some diseases. There are also personal trainers who can guide people to fitness goals. Is there anything like this for achieving academic goals?

Comment: 'personal trainers' -> experienced researchers who regularly publish in top venues or attract funding.  Learn from them.  However, my hypothesis is that these 'trainers' tend to have some x-factors (extremely creative, or high IQ) that set them apart from other mere mortals.  You can train with Usain Bolt all you want, but you will never hold the 100m world record.  Having said that, learning from the best lifts your level, and thus making you better equip to accomplish things that otherwise are beyond the reach of those who never underwent the same training.

Comment: 10 publish; 20 goto 10.

Comment: In the broadest meaning of "algorithm" (which can include a "set of rules"), I'm sure that every successful researcher follows one. But different successful researchers seem to follow different algorithms; for example: "have that one idea and apply it to everything" vs. "become an expert for many things and collaborate a lot".

Answer (score 2):

Academia is a highly competitive discipline.  One might compare it to professional sports, with landing a permanent position at a research university comparing to getting a contract with a team in the top league.  Is there an algorithm that anyone can follow to become better at football?  Yes; in fact there are many such algorithms that work reasonably well.  Will everyone following one of these algorithms become a Premier League player?  Hahahaha.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as "success" in academia. Are you successful if you reach a certain title in a faculty? When you get X quoted citations of your best paper? When you're well respected in your field?

You can define goals and cater your life around them. If you meet those goals, you can say that you're successful. Personally I would say that if you get awarded a PhD, you're already a success. From what I've seen and experienced, it usually turns into mostly politics and career fluff after that anyways. So, you can apply whatever algorithm for political success after that point.

Answer (score -3):

This is touched on by JeffE in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/154/).

> Nobody in theoretical computer science cares where you got your degree. Really. We. Do. Not. Care. We only care about the quality and visibility of your results. **Publish strong papers and give brilliant talks at top conferences. Convince well-known active researchers to write letters raving about your work. Make a good product and get superstars to sell it for you.** Do all that, and we'll definitely want to hire you, no matter where you got your degree. On the other hand, without a strong and visible research record, independent from your advisor, you are much less likely to get a good academic job, no matter where you got your degree.

Relevant parts highlighted.

One more thing to add is to have a track record of getting lots of funding.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's really a matter of how to accomplish the things in bold. Right now I'm a postdoc but I feel aimless and I don't know how to reach those goals. With some things there is no guesswork - it is mainly a matter of discipline. But it feels more like complete guessing in academia

Answer (score -4):

> There are algorithms/prescriptions for treating some diseases. There
> are also personal trainers who can guide people to fitness goals. Is
> there anything like this for achieving academic goals?

Yes there is. Don't do anything yourself like all academic leaders. Get someone else to do it, add your name when they are done. You submit the paper. As soon as it's accepted, you tell everybody on about your great research. Travel around the world giving presentations about your works.

Repeat the same strategy to as many papers as you can. Very soon, you'll build up a strong academic record. Everybody will know you. You don't need to know the topics. You just need to add yourself as the senior author, do the submission, telling everybody it's all about you.

They do the works you get the trophy.

Comment: Yeah, right. That's like beating level 5 monsters when you are at level 90. You just left out the most important part: how to get to level 90 in the first place?