# PhD at low rank university

Tags: phd, ranking

Is it advisable to do a PhD at low rank university (~700 QS) if the advisor is well known in the field and is actively involved in research.

Comment: This seems opinion based. But what alternatives do you have? No PhD? Another university and professor?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d) question and the accepted answer to it.

Comment: @Buffy well i have offers from colleges in my home country (200-400 QS) but the profiles of professors is quite underwhelming and also lots of them are not interested in research. (My experience during my MS from on of the top institutes in my country )

Answer (score 5):

QS ratings cover the whole institute. But in many universities there are a few really good research groups weighed down by a lot of weaker ones. In the appropriate research field people know that and will give due esteem to them. If the advisor is good and the research group is good then you will (hopefully) do good work and get the glory -  ignore the league tables.