# Choosing a Grad school from the perspective of opportunities in Academic Job market

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I have received Ph.D. offers from my 3 Top choices (with funding). I had five top choices (with no order) but I am expecting a rejection from 4th and my 5th top choice has frankly told me that he is not going to accept any Ph.D. student (at least for this year).

Now I am thinking to make a decision between the three choices

1. Univ A: A "mid-ranked" Univ (Rank 8 - 15); New Professor, Very strong record considering his age. Excellent thesis at a top Univ. (Rank < 3). I am getting a new and exciting topic for my Ph.D. thesis, which hardly anyone else except this Prof. and his PI works on.
2. Univ B: A slightly "Lower-ranked" Univ (Rank > 25); Well established and very well-known Professor (H-index>80). Ph.D. topic: Relatively popular topic but less exciting than at Univ A. Good industry opportunities.
3. Univ C: A slightly "higher-ranked" Univ (Rank 4 - 8); Well established Professor (not as reputed as the Prof. in Univ B).  Ph.D. topic: Relatively popular topic and almost same as that at Univ B but less exciting than at Univ A.

Which of the factors should I take into account if I aim to get a faculty position at a well-ranked (Rank < 15) US university or any other top Univ outside the US?

Assume roughly similar and above-80 percentile Ph.D. work (in terms of quality and number of papers).

Moreover, Will, I get any advantage (in the job market) if I choose Univ A as the supply of faculty with those skills is negligible? If I am able to clinch a Postdoc at an even higher ranked univ will that compensate for the "mid/Low rank" of Univ A, B?

Rank is based on my overall perception of the department (and not of any specific Research area).

Comment: Actually, you've listed the factors that you intend to consider. The rest depends on your personal choices.

Comment: The expected helpfulness of the potential advisor is a very important consideration, actually. Hard to judge from the exterior, of course.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes thanks. It provided great insights

Comment: Don't forget to consider what the potential advisor is like as a person! Try to meet them and their former students to understand what they're like to work with. It's no use being supervised by a someone with a big h-index if they're also horrible to their students.

Comment: @astronat I have one more doubt. If I can get famous persons in my Advising committee will that help?