# Role of university ranking in becoming a professor in Germany

Tags: postdocs, university, germany, early-career

There are different universities in Germany, like Hoschule, University, and the University of Excellence. While doing a PostDoc, apart from having a good publication. What is the importance of university rank and supervisor profile in becoming a junior professor?

Comment: How can we help you here? You have the pros and cons all listed out, now you just need to make a decision about it. Nobody but you can tell you whether it's worth the risk to go with a shorter contract at a potentially better place.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, thanks for comment, but joining THI will consider negative in terms of becoming a professor?

Comment: I voted to re-open since the new wording of the question is no longer based on individual factors.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d Does this answer your question?

Comment: As long as the the question is still closed, here are a few comments from a German perspective: (a) As far as Germany is concerned, forget about university rankings. They are essentially meaningless in Germany, and when it comes to hiring, nobody really cares about them. (b) Concerning "Exzellenzuniversitäten" - again, don't expect any reputation bonus from doing your postdoc at such a uni. It essentially means that the university applied for and got (significant amounts of) extra money. (This might have advantages in terms of equipment and such - but this will depend on various factors).

Comment: (c) There are two different types of institutions in tertiary education in Germany: universities and "Fachhochschulen" (although the latter apparently don't like to be called like this anymore, for some reason which is beyond me). (Re previous version of the question: RWTH Aachen is a university, TH Ingolstadt is a Fachhochschule).  If you're planning an academic career at universities, then doing a postdoc at a Fachhochschule might be seriously disadvantageous in some fields. (But this might be field-dependend to some extent, so it would probably be helpful to specify your field.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck, thanks for the answer; my field is social data science or computational social science.