# C+ in a core Master's class years ago. Will postdocs and/or employers mind it at all?

Tags: graduate-school, postdocs, career-path, job-search, psychology

I graduated with a Master's in Experimental psychology in 2020 with a C+ in research methods (core course and it actually counted even though other programs normally don't do that). Reason my grade was that low was because I finished a final project and final exam worth half of the class grade with severe dental pain from a dead tooth. At the time, accessible dental care was hours away. If I knew how incompletes for medical reasons worked, I would've just drove back and got a note from the dentist.

Finishing a Ph.D and got an A for their research methods equivalent when I took it there. Will employers care about the C+ if I apply for research positions (industry, post doc, etc.)? I understand that this concern is years after the fact, but I have heard of some instances where that matters to some.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Only the grades from your highest degree matters, and even then, [not a lot](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d).

> We only care about the quality and visibility of your results. Publish strong papers and give brilliant talks at top conferences. Convince well-known active researchers to write letters raving about your work. Make a good product and get superstars to sell it for you. Do all that, and we'll definitely want to hire you, no matter where you got your degree.

Though the above is for academic careers, the same goes for industry. If they care about your grades at all (which they probably won't; in most industry job applications they ask for your CV, not your transcripts) they'll look only at your PhD grades.